# How to add a new GridViewItem to a GridView when a GridViewItem is clicked?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have an idea like picture. But i don't know how to do it by code. Please help me. I'm a newbie.

[image]

This is my code that i wrote for show GridView

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Tabs}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Tab">
                <Grid Width="350" Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF035CA8" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Image Width="350" Source="{x:Bind Image }" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Margin="0,110,0,0" 
                          Height="40"
                          Width="350">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF035CA8" Opacity="0.34"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                                   Height="20"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   Text="{x:Bind tabName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid
```

Answer (score 1):

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <GridView
            x:Name="gv"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="gv_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ItemView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.items.Add(new ItemAddModel());
            this.gv.ItemsSource = this.items;
        }

        private void gv_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem is ItemAddModel)
            {
                this.items.Insert(this.items.Count - 1, new ItemModel { Text = $"Item {this.items.Count}" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ItemView.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App2.ItemView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid
        Background="White"
        Width="320"
        Height="240">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup
                x:Name="ItemOrAddStates">
                <VisualState
                    x:Name="ItemViewState"/>
                <VisualState
                    x:Name="ItemAddViewState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ItemViewTextBlock"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                KeyTime="0"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ItemAddTextBlock"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                KeyTime="0"
                                Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="ItemViewTextBlock"
            Margin="15"
            Text="{Binding Text}"
            FontSize="24" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="ItemAddTextBlock"
            Text="+"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="72" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ItemView.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class ItemView : UserControl
    {
        public ItemView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContextChanged += ItemView_DataContextChanged;
        }

        private void ItemView_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(
                this,
                args.NewValue is ItemModel
                ? "ItemViewState"
                : "ItemAddViewState",
                false);
        }
    }
}

class ItemAddModel
{
}

class ItemModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```